# Service Fabric specify fabric url

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to define which url a service uses instead of the standard `fabric:/AppName/ServiceName`?

I can't find if this is configurable or not on an application level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, you can change the name of the service in the `ApplicationManifest.xml` to something other than the name taken from the service's class name.

**Short:** just change the `name` attribute in `ApplicationManifest.xml` for that service to something else.

**In code:** If I have this service:

```cs
public interface IJustAnotherStatelessService : IService
{
    Task<string> SayHelloAsync(string someValue);
}

internal sealed class JustAnotherStatelessService : StatelessService, IJustAnotherStatelessService
{
     // Service implementation
}
```

Registered in `Program.cs` like this:

```cs
ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("JustAnotherStatelessServiceType",
    context => new JustAnotherStatelessService(context)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

And in the `ServiceManifest.xml` for that service

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest ...>
  <ServiceTypes>
    <!-- This is the name of your ServiceType. 
         This name must match the string used in RegisterServiceType call in Program.cs. -->
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="JustAnotherStatelessServiceType" />
  </ServiceTypes>
 ...
```

In the `ApplicationManifest.xml` you will get the suggested name:

```cs
<ApplicationManifest ...>
  <DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="JustAnotherStatelessService">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="JustAnotherStatelessServiceType" InstanceCount="[JustAnotherStatelessService_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

This will give you an Uri to you service like

```cs
fabric:/app_name/JustAnotherStatelessService
```

Now, go ahead and change the name in the application manifest:

```cs
<ApplicationManifest ...>
  <DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="AwesomeService">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="JustAnotherStatelessServiceType" InstanceCount="[JustAnotherStatelessService_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

And your service now answers to

```cs
fabric:/app_name/AwesomeService
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I believe I wasn't clear with my requirements. I wanted to know if you could make an application listen to `fabric:/foobarbazservice` but I do not think this is possible as the service resolver looks for the service type inside the application type and can't, say, choose one at random!

Comment: No, in that part you are right, you are limited to the {applicationName}/{serviceName_set_in_ApplicationManifest} scheme for the url. I dont see any way to set completely custom urls given the way fabric transport builds it's Url internaly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this uri builder (ServiceUriBuilder.cs) class from here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app/blob/master/ReferenceApp/Common/ServiceUriBuilder.cs

For stateless service you can easily get the proxy:

```
var serviceUri = new ServiceUriBuilder(ServiceName);
var proxyFactory = new ServiceProxyFactory();
var svc = proxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy<IServiceName>(serviceUri.ToUri());
```

For stateful service you have to specify the partition.

```
var serviceUri = new ServiceUriBuilder(StatefulServiceName);
var proxyFactory = new ServiceProxyFactory();
//this is just a sample of partition 1 if you are using number partitioning. 
var partition = new ServicePartitionKey(1);
var svc = proxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy<IStatefulServiceName>(serviceUri.ToUri(), partition);
```